# Multiple loops in Excel VBA

Tags: excel, loops, foreach, vba

I have a problem with creating multiple/nested loops. I could write a block of code and repeat it like 17 times with slight alterations every time, but I am trying to avoid this.

My code looks like the following and everything else is fine except the sections towards the end where I have added 'loop needed.

So basically the loop should include "AJ2, AK2,..., AZ2" and "1, 2,..., 17".

Any help will be much appreciated. I have struggled with this for weeks.

```
Sub Test()

Worksheets("SheetName").Activate
Range("A1").CurrentRegion.Copy
Worksheets("NewSheet").Activate

Range("A1").PasteSpecial
Range("A1").PasteSpecial xlPasteColumnWidths

Dim c As Range
Dim col1 As Range
Dim j As Integer
Dim Source As Worksheet
Dim Target As Worksheet
Dim lastrow As Long

Set Source = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("SheetName")
Set Target = ActiveWorkbook.Worksheets("NewSheet")
Set col1 = Source.Range("SheetName[Col]")

j = 2     

For Each c In col1
    If c >= Range("AJ2") Then 'loop needed with "AJ2"
       Source.Range("A" & c.Row & ":BN" & c.Row).Copy
       Target.Range("A" & Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       Target.Range("BO" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = DateAdd("m", 1, Range("BO2").Value) 'loop needed with 1
       j = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
Next c

For Each c In col1
    If c >= Range("AK2") Then 'loop needed with "AK2"
       Source.Range("A" & c.Row & ":BN" & c.Row).Copy
       Target.Range("A" & Range("E65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
       Target.Range("BO" & Rows.Count).End(xlUp).Value = DateAdd("m", 2, Range("BO2").Value) 'loop needed with 2
       j = Range("A65536").End(xlUp).Row + 1
    End If
Next c

End Sub
```

Comment: Write a *function* that takes `Range("AJ2")` &c. as a *parameter*

Answer (score 0):

Try using `cells([rownumber], [columnnumber])` instead of referencing range by name. This way you can easily do a loop with increasing numbers, rather than text.